Как сделать матрицу указанного размера из точек через пробел используя один цикл?
Нужно создать матрицу n на n, к примеру, n = 3. При этом матрица должна быть заполнена точками через пробел. Сама задача: создать матрицу какую я описал выше, при этом используя только один цикл. Использование библиотек или методов, которые напрямую выполняют задачу (если такие есть), не приветствуется.
Пример правильного вывода при n = 3: . . .(enter). . .(enter). . .
Важное уточнение: в конце строк не должно быть пробелов, тоесть такие варианты являются не правильными:  matrix = ['. '  * n for i in range(n)].
Тоесть нужно именно техническое решение.

print('\n'.join([' '.join(['.']*3)]*3))

Тоже оставлю вариант в комментариях, т.к. не подходит под условие задачи - с 1 циклом: print(('. ' * (n-1) + '.\n') * n, end='')

Лёгким движением руки неправильный код превращается в правильный: matrix = [('. '  * n)[:-1] for i in range(n)] Ну, это в качестве шутки, решение не оптимальное, конечно. Или даже так: matrix = [('. '  * n)[:-1]]*n

n = 5
_ = [print("."+" "*bool((x+1)%n)+ "\n"*(not(x+1)%n), end="") for x in range(n*n)]

. . . . .
. . . . .
. . . . .
. . . . .
. . . . .


def create_matrix(n):
    matrix = []
    row = []
    for i in range(n * n):
        row.append('.')
        if (i + 1) % n == 0:
            matrix.append(' '.join(row))
            row = []
    return matrix

n = 3
result = create_matrix(n)
for line in result:
    print(line)

